# DynamoDB flush latency

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

### Environment Description

We're using DynamoDB and Lambda in our code, the Lambda writes items to DynamoDB directly (meaning not through triggers or other async actions), and some small time after it another Lambda tries to read the item (through `get` not `scan` meaning it's the fastest).

Our code uses Python 3.6 (though it is not really relevant to the question).

### Problem

It seems that some times the second Lambda does not find the item, we know that the write is successful, and we can see the items in the DynamoDB.

### Question

The question is, what is the maximum time between a successful [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) and guaranteed [GetItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html)?

Should it be solved with some retry loop (preferably not)?

Also, is there a difference between calling [BatchWriteItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) with a single item and calling PutItem?

Comment: Are you using strongly consistent reads or eventually consistent reads?

Comment: What do you mean @Marcin? the GetItem is almost always on different keys.

Comment: DynamoDB GetItem operates in [two read modes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html): strong and eventual (default). Strong guarantees obtaining item after last write, while eventual does not. Could be the reason for your issue? Have you tried with strong consistency?

Comment: Thank you @Marcin, I will try it, do you know the answer to my last question, also, can you upvote the question if you think it might help others?

Comment: Let me know how it will go with strong consistency. I haven't seen your last question yet.

Comment: "Also, is there a difference between calling BatchWriteItem with a single item and calling PutItem?"

Comment: Ah:-). The only differance I'm aware is that BatchWriteItem is faster as you save on multiple API requests. I don't think there is any effect on read consistency.

Comment: Yes, but in the case of writing a single item, will it make any difference? is there a reason not to always use BatchWriteItem?

Comment: For writing single item only, I think there wouldn't be any difference. But programativly, I would use PutItem, as its self documenting in the code. `BatchWriteItem` suggests that you write multiple records, which can be confusing if someone looks at your code, and you just write 1 item.

Comment: How other lambda is invoked ? Are they in same region ?

Comment: Yes, another "orchestrator" Lambda invokes the two one by one, but I think @Marcin answered the question for me.

Comment: If you don't mind, I can provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: Go ahead @Marcin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue seems to be related to [read consistency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html) of `GetItem`. By default, `GetItem` uses Eventually Consistent reads:

> When you read data from a DynamoDB table, the response **might not reflect the results of a recently completed** write operation.

To overcome the limitation of the eventually consistent mode, strongly consistent reads can be used:

> DynamoDB returns a **response with the most up-to-date data**

Please note, that strongly consistent reads **cost twice** as much as eventually consistent reads. There are also other limitations to strongly consistent reads, described in the linked docs.

The alternative could be the use of  [exponential backoff](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) when using eventually consistent reads, until the `GetItem` succeeds.